# Throwing exception when inserting data in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am getting below warning when i inserting data.

```
Parallel.ForEach(user, data => Db.ExecuteQuery("insert into temptbl (userid,attflag,checktime,username)values('" +
                                                                     data.UserId + "','" + data.Flag + "','" + data.AttendanceDate + "','" +
                                                                     data.Name + "')"));
```

[image]

Comment: This would seem to be an error in the OleDb Provider. Which provider is it?

Comment: Also, have you tried it without the parallelism?

Comment: May be this link helps you http://michaelsync.net/2009/10/31/net-runtime-version-2-0-50727-3603-fatal-execution-engine-error-7a036050-80131506-mscoree-dll

Comment: @Keith without parallelism working fine..

Comment: Yeah, the code in your ExecuteQuery() method needs a lot of changes. Not sure why you're creating a new OleDbDataAdapter for executing a OleDbCommand that I assume you are passing into your ExecuteQuery() method (it is obscured in the image). To stick with the parallel execution, change the new OleDbAdapter to a new OleDbConnection and set the OleDbCommand to use that new connection and you *might* get past the exception. It also depends on the connection pooling. Regardless, it will perform more poorly than sequential execution.

Comment: This is one of those moments where you just have to say NO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database connection objects are not thread-safe and are not meant to be used in multiple threads at the same time.

You should not parallelize the code across a single connection, instead you will need a separate connection for each distinct thread, and thus you cannot use `Parallel.ForEach`.

You can see this documented on MSDN:

[OleDbConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx), Thread Safety section (near the bottom):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This means that static *members* of this type are thread-safe, instance-members are not, which means that the type as an object will not be thread-safe.